# How to divide two numbers without getting SyntaxError?

Tags: python, debugging

```
"car" = input("Enter the name of the car:")
"gas" = float(input("Enter gas used in gallons:"))
"miles" = float(input("Enter number of miles driven:") 
mpg = "miles" / "gas"
print ("Cars Name",car)
print ("Gallons of gas used:,gas)("Number of miles driven:,miles)            
print("Miles per Gallon",mpg)
```

I have tried multiple ways to write the division of miles by gas and I keep getting a syntax error. I am sure it is simple, I just do not know what else to try

Comment: Post the full traceback so that we can easily see the problem. Its pretty obvious in this case, but generally its needed.

Comment: You should be getting errors before the division. Don't enclose all the variable names in quotes. Instead write things like this: `car = input("Enter the name of the car:")` and `mpg = miles / gas`, etc.

Comment: Please think carefully about why you did **not** write `"mpg" = "miles" / "gas"`, but instead left `mpg` outside of any quotation marks. Then carefully consider whether the same principle applies anywhere else in your code.

Comment: There are many typos in this code. Doing programming requires paying close attention to detail. Think carefully about what the quotation mark is for, and then think carefully about exactly every place where it should and should not go in the code, according to what you are trying to do. Also think carefully about matching up your parentheses.

Comment: Also, try to *read* error messages. When you see, for example, `SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal`, the first thing you should make sure is that you understand what the words `syntax`, `assign` and `literal` mean. If you don't, then *look them up in a dictionary*. Then try to understand the entire message, and relate it to the line of code that it refers to.

Answer (score 2):

`"car"` is a string literal, and you can't assign something to a literal. What would it mean to assign a value to `10` for instance? `car` is a variable. Also, the details matter in programming. Every opening parenthesis needs a closing one. Every quote character also needs a paired quote to close the string.

With a little cleanup, your program works

```
car = input("Enter the name of the car:")
gas = float(input("Enter gas used in gallons:"))
miles = float(input("Enter number of miles driven:")) 
mpg = miles / gas
print ("Cars Name",car)
print ("Gallons of gas used: ",gas)
print("Number of miles driven: ",miles)            
print("Miles per Gallon: ", mpg)
```